# Aligning of equations within derivations

Tags: equations, align

Okay, so I have the following derivation so far in my latex document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel} %francais, polish, spanish, ...
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{0cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0cm}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    %\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    %    \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
    %    \par\nobreak
    %    \vskip 20\p@
    %\fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \thechapter \space \space \space \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 10\p@
  }}
  \makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% DOCUMENT
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    F_{x_t}(h-h_3) + (F_{z_t} + mgcos\phi - 2F_{z_1})a_2 - 2h(F_{x_1} + F_{x_2}) - 2F_{z_1}a_1 - F_{z_t}(a_2 + b_1) = 0 \nonumber 
\end{align} 
\begin{align}
    2F_{z_1}(a_1 + a_2) &= F_{x_t}(h - h_3) + (F_{z_t} + mgcos\phi)a_2 -2h(F_{x_1} + F_{x_2}) - F_{z_t}(a_2 + b_1) \nonumber \\
    &= A_2sin\phi(h - h_3) + mga_2cos\phi - 2hA_1sin\phi - b_1(A_3sin\phi + B_3cos\phi) \nonumber \\
    &= sin\phi\big(A_2(h - h_3) -2hA_1 -b_1A_3 \big) + cos\phi \big(mga_2 - b_1B_3 \big) \nonumber
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\therefore F_{z_1} = A_4sin\phi + B_4cos\phi
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, there are 5 lines in the derivation (i.e between `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` statements. However, the middle 3 need to be aligned w.r.t to the equals sign, and the top and bottom line should be centred. I've sort of managed to achieve it this way, but I want a way of doing it without 3 align blocks, is this possible?

Comment: The `a4wide` package is deprecated. Use `geometry` for setting the page parameters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use ordinary `equation` and/or `equation*` environments for the first and last equation. Also, if every single line in an `align` environment gets a `\notag` statement to suppress an equation number, it's much better to use an `align*` environment and drop all those `\notag` statements.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{lmodern,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{0cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
F_{x_t}(h-h_3) + (F_{z_t} + mg\cos\phi - 2F_{z_1})a_2 - 2h(F_{x_1} + F_{x_2}) - 2F_{z_1}a_1 - F_{z_t}(a_2 + b_1) = 0
\end{equation*}    
\begin{align*}
2F_{z_1}(a_1 + a_2) &= F_{x_t}(h - h_3) + (F_{z_t} + mg\cos\phi)a_2 -2h(F_{x_1} + F_{x_2}) - F_{z_t}(a_2 + b_1) \\
&= A_2\sin\phi(h - h_3) + mga_2\cos\phi - 2hA_1\sin\phi - b_1(A_3\sin\phi + B_3\cos\phi) \\
&= \sin\phi\big(A_2(h - h_3) -2hA_1 -b_1A_3 \big) + \cos\phi \big(mga_2 - b_1B_3 \big)
\end{align*}         
\begin{equation}
\therefore F_{z_1} = A_4\sin\phi + B_4\cos\phi
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

**Addendum** If you want to eliminate the extra whitespace between the groups of equations, you could proceed by using a `split` environment inside a `gather` environment (with `\notag` directives for all but the final expression):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{lmodern,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{0cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
F_{x_t}(h-h_3) + (F_{z_t} + mg\cos\phi - 2F_{z_1})a_2 - 2h(F_{x_1} + F_{x_2}) - 2F_{z_1}a_1 - F_{z_t}(a_2 + b_1) = 0\notag\\
\begin{split}
2F_{z_1}(a_1 + a_2) &= F_{x_t}(h - h_3) + (F_{z_t} + mg\cos\phi)a_2 -2h(F_{x_1} + F_{x_2}) - F_{z_t}(a_2 + b_1) \notag\\
&= A_2\sin\phi(h - h_3) + mga_2\cos\phi - 2hA_1\sin\phi - b_1(A_3\sin\phi + B_3\cos\phi) \notag\\
&= \sin\phi\big(A_2(h - h_3) -2hA_1 -b_1A_3 \big) + \cos\phi \big(mga_2 - b_1B_3 \big) \end{split} \notag\\ 
\therefore F_{z_1} = A_4\sin\phi + B_4\cos\phi
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes I wondered about that too, it depends on the style of reference to (1) whether you want to just refer to the final step as here or if you want (1) to label the entire derivation. +1 anyway, see which the OP picks:-)

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps

[image]

Note you should always use `\cos` not `cos` and similar multi-letter identifiers The default math italic font is not designed for multi-letter words.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel} %francais, polish, spanish, ...
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{0cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0cm}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    %\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    %    \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
    %    \par\nobreak
    %    \vskip 20\p@
    %\fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \thechapter \space \space \space \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 10\p@
  }}
  \makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% DOCUMENT
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\begin{aligned}
                F_{x_t}(h-h_3) + (F_{z_t} + mg\cos\phi - 2F_{z_1})a_2 - 2h(F_{x_1} + F_{x_2}) - 2F_{z_1}a_1 - F_{z_t}(a_2 + b_1) = 0\\[\jot]
\begin{aligned}
                2F_{z_1}(a_1 + a_2) &= F_{x_t}(h - h_3) + (F_{z_t} + mg\cos\phi)a_2 -2h(F_{x_1} + F_{x_2}) - F_{z_t}(a_2 + b_1)  \\
                &= A_2\sin\phi(h - h_3) + mga_2\cos\phi - 2hA_1\sin\phi - b_1(A_3\sin\phi + B_3\cos\phi)  \\
                &= \sin\phi\big(A_2(h - h_3) -2hA_1 -b_1A_3 \big) + \cos\phi \big(mga_2 - b_1B_3 \big)
\end{aligned}\\[\jot]
                \therefore F_{z_1} = A_4\sin \phi + B_4\cos\phi 
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I prefer this answer as it removes the whitespace between the blocks. However, is there any way to make the last line aligned to the left or centred rather than the right?

Comment: @KeirSimmons simplest is to put an `&` before each of the lines of the outer `aligned` so before `F` before the second `\begin{aligned}` and before `\therefore`

Answer (score 3):

i suggest wrapping the whole thing in a single `gather`, use `aligned` to group the middle three lines, and use `\nonumber` on the first line and just before the (explicit) line break after `\end{aligned}` so that only one number appears for the whole structure.

```
\begin{gather}
  F_{x_t}(h-h_3) + (F_{z_t} + mg\cos\phi - 2F_{z_1})a_2 - 2h(F_{x_1} + F_{x_2}) - 2F_{z_1}a_1 - F_{z_t}(a_2 + b_1) = 0 \nonumber \\
  \begin{aligned}
    2F_{z_1}(a_1 + a_2) &= F_{x_t}(h - h_3) + (F_{z_t} + mg\cos\phi)a_2 -2h(F_{x_1} + F_{x_2}) - F_{z_t}(a_2 + b_1) \\
       &= A_2\sin\phi(h - h_3) + mga_2\cos\phi - 2hA_1\sin\phi - b_1(A_3\sin\phi + B_3\cos\phi) \\
       &= \sin\phi\big(A_2(h - h_3) -2hA_1 -b_1A_3 \big) + \cos\phi \big(mga_2 - b_1B_3 \big)
  \end{aligned} \nonumber \\
  \therefore F_{z_1} = A_4\sin\phi + B_4\cos\phi
\end{gather}
```

any "line" within the scope of `gather` will be centered; the `aligned` block will be treated as a single "line" for this purpose.

as Mico suggests in a comment, "sin" and "cos" are more appropriately set as operators with the commands `\sin` and `\cos`.

Comment: You may also wish to recommend writing `\sin` and `\cos` instead of just `sin` and `cos`... :-)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can do it without `align` environment, instead using `stackengine`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel} %francais, polish, spanish, ...
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{0cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0cm}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}[2013-09-11]
\begin{document}
\stackMath\setstackgap{S}{1.5em}\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
\begin{equation}
\savestack{\temp}{\Longunderstack[l]{%
  = F_{x_t}(h - h_3) + (F_{z_t} + mg\cos\phi)a_2 -2h(F_{x_1} + F_{x_2}) - F_{z_t}(a_2 + b_1)\\
 = A_2\sin\phi(h - h_3) + mga_2\cos\phi - 2hA_1\sin\phi - b_1(A_3\sin\phi + B_3\cos\phi)\\
  = \sin\phi\big(A_2(h - h_3) -2hA_1 -b_1A_3 \big) + \cos\phi \big(mga_2 - b_1B_3 \big)}%
}
\Shortstack{%
F_{x_t}(h-h_3) + (F_{z_t} + mg\cos\phi - 2F_{z_1})a_2 - 2h(F_{x_1} + F_{x_2}) - 2F_{z_1}a_1 - F_{z_t}(a_2 + b_1) = 0\\
2F_{z_1}(a_2 + b_1)\mathrel{\temp}\\%
\therefore F_{z_1} = A_4\sin\phi + B_4\cos\phi%
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```